# Difference between IsDesign vs PortalContext.IsDesignMode()

Tags: c#, content-management-system, kentico

I just start to learn Kentico 9 and trying to make custom web parts layout (https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/developing-web-parts/advanced-web-part-development-scenarios/developing-layout-web-parts). In their sample code they have:

```
if (IsDesign)
{
    Append("<table class=\"LayoutTable\" cellspacing=\"0\">");

    if (PortalContext.IsDesignMode(this.ViewMode))
    {
        Append("<tr><td class=\"LayoutHeader\" colspan=\"2\">");

        // Adds a header container.
        AddHeaderContainer();

        Append("</td></tr>");
    }

    Append("<tr><td>");
}
```

I'm confused about the difference between IsDesign property and PortalContext.IsDesignMode() method. Did they work is same manner? If no, in which situation they will yield different value?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMSAbstractWebPart.IsDesign` adds some extra logic which makes it more robust and reliable (it covers some edge cases like livesite editing etc.) Use that one.